# How can i make a comment box with an arrow centered on the right border

Tags: html, css

Something like this but i want the arrow to be on the right border and centered. Will it be responsive?

```css
The CSS
.left {
  width: 920px !important;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  min-height: auto !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: left;
 }

 .left > p:first-of-type { 
  background: #ffd987; 
  font-style: italic; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  margin-bottom: 40px;
 }

 .tip {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
 }

 .tip:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: 98px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
 }

 .tip:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 99px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #fff;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  content: '';
 }

 .tip.left:before {
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: -28px;
  top: 20px;
 }

 .tip.left:after {
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  left: -24px;
  top: 22px;
 }
```

```html
The html
<div style="padding:50px">
 
 <div class="tip left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `transform: translate`

```css
.left {
    width: 920px !important;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: auto !important;
    padding-right: 0;
    float: left;
}
.left > p:first-of-type {
    background: #ffd987;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.tip {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.tip:before, 
.tip:after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute; top: 50%; right: -28px;
    border: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 14px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
.tip:after {
    border-left: 14px solid white;
    right: -27px; 
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:50px">
    <div class="tip left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/dog8mdkf/

Comment: THe arrow is centered but i want it to be on the right not left. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you change the direction of the arrow and center it vertically

```
.tip.left:before {
  border-right: 14px solid #fff;
  right: -28px;
  top: 50%;
}

.tip.left:after {
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following way you can do it:

```css
.left {
  width: 920px !important;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  min-height: auto !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: left;
 }

 .left > p:first-of-type { 
  background: #ffd987; 
  font-style: italic; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  margin-bottom: 40px;
 }

 .tip {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
 }

 .tip:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
 }

 .tip:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #fff;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  content: '';
 }

 .tip.left:before{
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right:-28px;
  top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 .tip.left:after {
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  right: -24px;
  top: 51.5%;
    transform: translateY(-57%);
 }
```

```html
<div style="padding:50px">
 
 <div class="tip left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
 </div>
</div>
```

Refer [css-triangles](http://callmenick.com/post/css-triangles) and [Link](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles) for more info.